# Preserving 'this' context in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

This question is already asked and the solution proposed is of using 'bind'. But how to use 'bind' for this case ?

```
var Fun = function(){
    this.count = 100;
}

Fun.prototype.f = function(){
    console.log("in f : " + this.count);
}

Fun.prototype.g = {
    f : function(){
        console.log("in g-f : " + this.count);
        // Is it possible to use 'bind' here to access 'this' of 'Fun'
    }
}

fun = new Fun();
fun.f(); // Results - in f : 100
fun.g.f(); // Results - in g-f : undefined
fun.g.f.bind(fun)(); // Results - in f : 100
```

Is it possible to use `bind` in `g.f` such that `fun.g.f()` will give the result `in f : 100` ?

Comment: @NEB: it's not possible, those are 2 different objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to use 'bind' here to access 'this' of 'Fun'

No, because there's no `this` to bind at the point you're creating the second `f`. You'd have to do it in `Fun` instead:

```
var Fun = function(){
    this.count = 100;
    this.g = {
        f: function() {
            console.log("in g-f : " + this.count);
        }.bind(this)
    };
};
```

Or without bind:

```
var Fun = function(){
    var t = this;
    this.count = 100;
    this.g = {
        f: function() {
            console.log("in g-f : " + t.count);
        }
    };
};
```

This does involve creating a new function for every instance. Modern browser engines will reuse the function's *code* between instances even though distinct function *objects* are created.

If you wanted to make the main body of `f` used from the prototype, that's also possible: Put `g` on the prototype as you've shown, then:

```
var Fun = function(){
    var t = this;
    var oldg = this.g;
    this.count = 100;
    this.g = {
        f: function() {
            return oldg.f.apply(t, arguments);
        }
    };
};
```

Now, if `Fun.prototype.g.f` changes after the instance is created, you use the updated version. But if `Fun.prototype.g` is replaced with a reference to a new object, it'll break.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this solution. But as you said, I was trying to avoid 'creation of new function for every instance'.

Comment: @NEB: You basically can't prior to ES6's `Proxy` feature -- which would also involve creating a function (to handle the proxy callbacks) probably per instance.

Comment: @NEB It is a 'well optimized' scenario, even though it does incur some slight book-keeping overhead. This is common in code structures that employ such for 'private' methods (or otherwise need to maintain a specific binding) anyway.. unless dealing in the {insert some relevant value} thousands of objects, I wouldn't even bat an eye if this approach did what I needed/wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, as `fun.g` is a different object. All you can do is to put a differnet `g` object in all instances of `Fun`, and put a bound function `f` in there.

```
function Fun() {
  this.count = 100;

  this.g = {
    f: function() {
      console.log("in g-f : " + this.count);
    }.bind(this);
  };
}

Fun.prototype.f = function() {
  console.log("in f : " + this.count);
};
```